# Calcular interseccion de dos Rectas en PHP GD

Tags: php, php7, gd

Estoy intentando realizar una formula para hayar la intersección de dos segmentos dibujado en la libreria GD de PHP.

```
function intersection ( $ax1, $ay1, $ax2, $ay2, $bx1, $by1, $bx2, $by2 ) {

$a1 = $ay2 - $ay1;
$b1 = $ax1 - $ax2;
$c1 = ( $a1 * $ax1 ) + ( $b1 * $ay1 );

$a2 = $by2 - $by1;
$b2 = $bx1 - $bx2;
$c2 = ( $a2 * $bx1 ) + ( $b2 * $by1 );

$x = ( $b2 * $c1 ) - ( $b1 * $c2 );
$y = ( $a1 * $c2 ) - ( $a2 * $c1 );

return array ( 'x' => $x, 'y' => $y );
```

}

Esta seria la funcion que he realizado.
Pero a la hora de introducir los datos, no me devuelve la posición correcta de la intersección.

```
$cb = intersection( 0, 163, 123, 256, 0, 133, 93, 256 );
```

El valor devuelto es:
X: 343170;
Y: 1315710;

Algo que se sale.
Donde esta el fallo?
Un saludo y gracias de antemano.

Comment: Los datos que pasas son las coordenadas de 2 puntos para cada recta. ¿Verdad? Luego, ya me pierdo, porque realmente no sé de donde sacas las ecuaciones que planteas.

Comment: Hola @Mauricio Conteras, gracias por contestar. Si, las coordenadas introducidas son de dos segmentos que se que se cruzan. La ecuación la encontré en varios foros de matemáticos y programadores por lo que intente ponerla a prueba para obtener las coordenadas de la intersección entre los dos segmentos, pero no funciona correctamente y no encuentro el error en la ecuación.

Comment: La ecuación esta mal, al principio parece que intenta usar el método de los determinantes, pero luego ya no lo hace. Ese es el error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema está en la fórmula que usas para calcular el punto de intersección de dos rectas en el mismo plano. Además no estás tomando en cuenta el caso de rectas paralelas, coincidentes o no. Y tampoco consideras el caso en que las coordenadas introducidas estén repetidas o incluyan al punto de intersección.

El algoritmo matemático que se usa normalmente para calcular el punto de intersección de dos rectas en el plano, cuando se conocen 2 puntos diferentes de cada recta, implica el uso de determinantes. La fórmula resultante del desarrollo de los determinantes contiene una división. El denominador de dicha operación determinará si las rectas se cortan o no. Si el denominador es cero, significa que las rectas son paralelas (no se cortan).

**PROBLEMA**

Se desea calcular el punto de intersección de dos rectas en el mismo plano, de las cuales se conocen las coordenadas de 2 puntos distintos (de cada recta). La función debe devolver el valor las coordenadas (x,y) del punto de intersección de cada recta. Si las rectas son paralelas o casi paralelas (ver nota al pie), la función devolverá `null`.

**SOLUCIÓN**

La fórmula para calcular la intersección de 2 rectas en el mismo plano es la siguiente:

Sean (x1,y1) y (x2,y2) las coordenadas de dos puntos diferentes de L1, (x3,y3) y (x4,y4) las coordenadas de 2 puntos diferentes de L2, entonces las coordenadas (xp,yp) del punto de intersección L1  L2 vienen dadas por:

```
xp = ((x1*y2 - y1*x2)*(x3 - x4) - (x1 - x2)*(x3*y4 - x4*y3)) / ((x1 - x2)*(y3 - y4) - (y1 - y2)*(x3 - x4))

yp = ((x1*y2 - y1*x2)*(y3 - y4) - (y1 - y2)*(x3*y4 - y3*x4)) / ((x1 - x2)*(y3 - y4) - (y1 - y2)*(x3 - x4))
```

Como puede apreciarse, en ambas fórmulas el denominador es el mismo. Si las rectas son paralelas, el denominador será igual a cero, por lo tanto la división no podrá ejecutarse (dará un error de `divide by zero`).

Ya usando esta fórmula puedes resolver tu problema. Sin embargo la idea es aportar un código funcional, por lo tanto completaré el ejercicio por si es de utilidad para alguien más.

Crearemos una función que recibirá 4 objetos, cada objeto representa un punto, cada punto contiene sus coordenadas en el plano.

La función calculará los menores y el denominador, luego realiza las operaciones para calcular las coordenadas (x,y) del punto de intersección. La función devuelve un objeto que representa un punto.

El código puede quedar así: (asumo que los datos se reciben mediante un método POST)

```
<?php
  class punto {
    public $x;
    public $y;
    public function __construct() {
      $args = func_get_args();
      $i = func_num_args();
      if (method_exists($this,$f='__construct'.$i)) {
        call_user_func_array(array($this,$f), $args);
      }
    }

    public function __construct2($x,$y) {
      $this->x = (float)$x;
      $this->y = (float)$y;
    }

    public function setCoords($x,$y) {
      $this->x = (float)$x;
      $this->y = (float)$y;
    }
  } //fin class punto

  function interseccion($pto_1, $pto_2, $pto_3, $pto_4) {
    //debemos verificar que las coordenadas son diferentes
    if ($pto_1->x == $pto_2->x && $pto_1->y == $pto_2->y || $pto_3->x == $pto_4->x && $pto_3->y == $pto_4->y) {
      // no se puede calcular una recta usando solo un punto
      return NULL;
    //ahora verificamos si por casualidad uno de los puntos es común
    } else if (($pto_1->x == $pto_3->x && $pto_1->y == $pto_3->y) || ($pto_1->x == $pto_4->x && $pto_1->y == $pto_4->y)) {
      //$pto_1 es el punto de interseccion
      return $pto_1;
    } else if (($pto_2->x == $pto_3->x && $pto_2->y == $pto_3->y) || ($pto_2->x == $pto_4->x && $pto_2->y == $pto_4->y)) {
      //$pto_2 es el punto de interseccion
      return $pto_2;
    // si todos los puntos son diferentes calculamos
    } else {
      //primero calculamos el denominador
      $denominador = (($pto_1->x - $pto_2->x) * ($pto_3->y - $pto_4->y)) - (($pto_1->y - $pto_2->y) * ($pto_3->x - $pto_4->x));
      if ($denominador == 0) {
        //las rectas son paralelas
        return NULL;
      } else {
        //calculamos los menores
        $menor1 = ($pto_1->x * $pto_2->y) - ($pto_1->y * $pto_2->x);
        $menor2 = ($pto_3->x * $pto_4->y) - ($pto_3->y * $pto_4->x);
        // calculamos la coordenada X
        $px = (($menor1 * ($pto_3->x - $pto_4->x)) - (($pto_1->x - $pto_2->x) * $menor2)) / $denominador;
        // calculamos la coordenada Y
        $py = (($menor1 * ($pto_3->y - $pto_4->y)) - (($pto_1->y - $pto_2->y) * $menor2)) / $denominador;

        $ptoInterseccion = new punto($px, $py);
        return $ptoInterseccion;
      }
    }
  } //fin funcion interseccion

  $punto_1 = new punto($_POST["p1_x"],$_POST["p1_y"]);
  $punto_2 = new punto($_POST["p2_x"],$_POST["p2_y"]);
  $punto_3 = new punto($_POST["p3_x"],$_POST["p3_y"]);
  $punto_4 = new punto($_POST["p4_x"],$_POST["p4_y"]);

  $pto_interseccion = interseccion($punto_1, $punto_2, $punto_3, $punto_4);

  echo json_encode($pto_interseccion);
?>
```

Espero que esto resuelva tu duda.

**NOTA**

El método de los determinantes aqui planteado presenta un desafío numérico al aplicarlo en computadora. El problema es debido a que los equipos informáticos no pueden representar con exactitud los números pequeños (que se acercan a cero) o las magnitudes muy grandes (que tienden a infinito). Así, si las rectas se intersecan en un punto del plano que no podemos representar en un equipo informático, este algoritmo dará como resultado que las rectas son paralelas.

Comment: Si la precisión complica los cálculos, hay un par de extensiones que permiten extender un poco las limitaciones del tipo float http://php.net/manual/en/refs.math.php

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias @Mauricio Conteras. Pero justo hace unos segundos, he resuleto el problema de la formula matematica y ahora si me da valores correctos, por fin me saca las coordenadas X e Y de la intersección. Muchas gracias igualmente por tu respuesta. Un saludo.
Comparto la formula por si alguien la quisiera usar:

```
function intersection ( $ax1, $ay1, $ax2, $ay2, $bx1, $by1, $bx2, $by2 ) {

    $a1 = $ax1 - $ax2;
    $a2 = $bx1 - $bx2;

    $b1 = $ay1 - $ay2;
    $b2 = $by1 - $by2;

    $c = ( $a1 * $b2 ) - ( $b1 * $a2 );

    if ( abs ( $c ) > 0.01 ) { // En caso de que haya interseccion

        $a = ( $ax1 * $ay2 ) - ( $ay1 * $ax2 );
        $b = ( $bx1 * $by2 ) - ( $by1 * $bx2 );

        $x = ( $a * $a2 - $b * $a1 ) / $c;
        $y = ( $a * $b2 - $b * $b1 ) / $c;

    } else { // En caso de que no lo haya

        $x = 0;
        $y = 0;

    }

    return array ( 'x' => $x, 'y' => $y );

 }
```